How to say "busy" in French
I'm confused about how to say "busy" - such as it's busy on the beach.  I have seen various translations such as:

Il y a du monde sur la plage.
C'est bondé sur la plage.
C'est très peuplé sur la plage.
La plage est très fréquentée.
La plage est très occupée.

Which are correct and what would a French person say?

The last is the only odd-souding one.

Yes, people, restrooms, phone lines or seats can be occupés but that doesn't work with a beach.

All expressions are grammatical. All can plausibly be said by native speakers, except the last one: instead they would say "la plage est {bondée | peuplée | surpeuplée}". You would also sound OK with "suroccupée", however the idea to use it is foreign (at least in France; dunno about Canada).


« La plage est très occupée » ne se dit pas, et pourrait entrainer une mauvaise compréhension.
« C'est très peuplé sur la plage » ne se dit pas, mais serait comprise par un Français.
« Il y a du monde sur la plage » et « La plage est très fréquentée », c'est parfait. La première phrase est plus courante.
« C'est bondé sur la plage », se dit, mais bondé est un terme fort, qui signifie qu'il y a énormément de monde, et que l'on va avoir du mal à trouver de la place sur la plage, davantage que lorsqu'on dit « Il y a du monde sur la plage. »


A much better translation would be "La plage est bondée" instead of C'est bondé sur la plage.


La plage est bondée aujourd'hui.


C'est une plage très fréquentée en été.


Il y a beaucoup de monde sur la plage, c'est très animé.


The first four versions would be used frequently by most people without much distinction. When arriving at the beach and seeing the amount of people, you would say:

Il y a du monde.
C'est bondé !
C'est peuplé / Il y a du peuple.
C'est très fréquenté ici.


The beach is busy (it's busy on the beach).

La plage est bondée.


La plage fourmille de monde.


La plage est noire de monde.

I am very busy.

Je suis très occupé(e).

The phone line is busy.

La ligne (de téléphone) est occupée.

I've had a busy day.

J'ai eu une journée bien remplie.

This will keep me busy for a week.

Cela va m'occuper pendant une semaine.

This street is very busy.

Cette rue est très fréquentée.

